# antMatchers() is not working , and gives forbidden error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I have an end-point called **authenticate** , this endpoint is given to antMatchers("/authenticate") to skip authorization for this end-point, but it still checks for the authentication.

code:

```
   @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // We don't need CSRF for this example
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            // dont authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            // all other requests need to be authenticated
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: `permitAll` doesn't mean no-security. There still needs to be an authentication object but it could be an anonymous one. Also are you sure the pattern is correct and that the url is `/authenticate` and not something else?

Comment: The pattern is correct, instead of permitAll(), what else can we use to stop checking for authorization in the end-point?

Comment: What does that endpont do? Shouldn't your JWT filter already decode the token and set the authentication? Why would you need an endpoint for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an update regarding the issue.

In my case, I had a problem with a function **singWith()** that was deprecated, the request of /authenticate was passing the **antMatchers()** filter but was not able to generate the token.

After the research, I found that there are other types of the same function, which works fine.

the old version of the token generation code.

```
SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode("newworldorder"));
```

**Key is of SecretKey type**

```
Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(date)
            .setExpiration(new Date(validity)
            .signWith(key).compact();
```

here is the new version of the token generation code.

```
private String key = "newworldorder";
```

**Key is of String type**

```
Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(date)
            .setExpiration(validity)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key).compact();
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this method it make sure this endpoint is ignored.

```
@Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authenticate");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was not a problem with antMatchers(), it was another problem with a deprecated function.

Answer (score 1):

If cannot be evaluated, just pass through at your authentication filter.

```java
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest req,
        final HttpServletResponse res,
        final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String header = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            // if cannot be evaluated
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        // do authentication

        // SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication() if authenticated normally
        // throw AuthenticationException if received illegal credentials

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

See also [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#attemptAuthentication()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.3/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) javadoc:

> The implementation should do one of the following:
>
> 1. Return a populated authentication token for the authenticated user, indicating successful authentication
> 2. Return null, indicating that the authentication process is still in progress. Before returning, the implementation should perform any additional work required to complete the process.
> 3. Throw an AuthenticationException if the authentication process fails